# Example of a Grothendieck fibration has fibred product (or other universal structure) but total category doesn't has product?

Tags: category-theory, type-theory

It is all in the title.

find an example of a fibration $p:\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{B}$, so that $p$ has fibred product, but $\mathcal{C}$ doesn't have product

Comment: Just take the [codomain fibration](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/codomain+fibration) defined with respect to a category with pullbacks but without binary products. An example of such a category is the category with objects sets and injective maps as morphisms.

Answer (score 0):

Just take the codomain fibration defined with respect to a category with pullbacks but without binary products. An example of such a category is the category with objects sets and injective maps as morphisms. – Nex 52 mins ago